# www.youtube.com redirects to the localhost after installing Apache

Tags: apache, youtube-api, localhost

I remember adding localhost and www.youtube.com to a document in an effort to get the Youtube API up and running which I probably shouldn't have.

Does anyone know what to do or what file I should look to edit?

[image: screenshot of browser with YouTube's URL in the address bar and a plain white page that just says "It works!" in the window]

And finally...

[image: screenshot of browser with localhost in the address bar and a plain white page that just says "It works!" in the window]

Comment: probably your `hosts` file... next time keep track of the changes you did, instead of just blindly messing around.

Comment: Thanks Marc B yes, noted for the future. I'm not sure where the host file is unfortunately. I've looked in /Library/WebServer/Documents (I'm on a mac)

Comment: `/private/etc/hosts`, probably, for macs.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Found it. Not sure why I was editing it to begin with. If you answer I can give you the credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on **Windows**, edit the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file.

If you are on **Linux**, edit the `/etc/hosts` file.

If you are on **Mac**, edit the `/private/etc/hosts` file.

Answer (score 1):

Hosts file must be. C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc

Comment: Thanks I'm on a mac, I've checked /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and the value for DocumentRoot is "/Library/WebServer/Documents", but at this path I can't find anything...any ideas?